# Is it possible to instantiate empty object/object without parameters from constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop

In code:

```
function Foo() {
    this.someMethod = function() {
        console.log("property");
    };
}
```

Is possible to instantiate empty Foo object, and call someMethod on it? Like:

```
Foo.someMethod();
```

I got TypeError, which means not.

Ok, next, can I define default method like with __construct in PHP which execute some code upon instantiation of object, or even better let make evaluation of that function be some property value inside object, so even when I instantiate "empty" object, that function set some value upon instantiation of new object.

Comment: `Foo` **is** the constructor, you should add the methods to the `prototype`, then simply create a new isntance with `new Foo().someMethod()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are doing it,

```
var fooObj = new Foo(); 
fooObj.someMethod();
```

will work fine.

---

You can also try doing it this way:

```
var Foo = (function(){

    function Foo() {
        // Foo constructor
    }

    Foo.prototype.someMethod = function(){
        // public Foo function
    };

    var somePrivateFunction = function(){
        // private Foo function
    };

    return Foo;

})();

var fooObj = new Foo();
```

Comment: I think you need a `return Foo` in there ...

Comment: I __knew__ I was forgetting something @Pointy Thanks ^_^

Comment: I'm really confused now. Let's try this, can I call method on object constructor directly? Like `Foo.someMethod()` without creating new instance with new keyword?

Comment: Not unless you do `Foo.someMethod = function(){ ... }` @AlanKis

Comment: @Neal I get it now. In ^ case when i call method on class, do I instantiate new object which appears in global scope or just caling method on function, because constructor as it is, is only function?